# Eclipse and GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have installed the GWT plugin in eclipse, how run the following code? I am new, can anybody show me graphically?

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsClient.html#hello

Comment: Have you read the rest of the tutorials? I'm sure Google has documentation on how to run your code...

Comment: i did not understand how to create project

Comment: possible duplicate of [please help me to write this code  in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351473/please-help-me-to-write-this-code-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the steps in the [Quick Start Guide](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html)? The User Manual also has a **whole page** dedicated to [Creating a New Web Application](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/creating_new_webapp.html). With screen shots.